# What does $q>0$ mean when $q \in \Bbb R^n$?

Tags: notation

Is it $q_i>0 \; \forall i=\{1,\dots,n\}$ or $\exists i \; s.t. q_i>0$?

Comment: It usually means that all $q_i$ are positive.

Comment: This notion depends on the author.  You have to consult the text or wherever this came from.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool. I'm the author, and I was trying to convey the first meaning, but it looks like I'll need to be more specific than $q>0$.

Comment: Then, you simply need to define the notation if you want to avoid confusion.  My take is that I don't like to use $q>0$ to mean that $q_i>0$ for every $i$.  I prefer to use $q>0$ to mean $q_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ but $q_j>0$ for some $j$.